# Storing an array of structs in a linked list

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array of struts called arrayOfElements , each element being a struct called Element

```
typedef struct {
    void* data;
    } Element;
```

data is a void pointer as I dont know in advanced what type of variable will be stored

I've malloc'd this array to have 4 elements ( this is done by user input but ive hard coded 4 for this question)

```
Element* arrayOfElements;
arrayOfElements= malloc(4 * sizeof(Element));
```

Now to this point I can store strings and ints in arrayOfElements

Store Int

```
arrayOfElements[0].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
int *ptr = arrayOfElements[0].data;
*ptr = 65;
```

Store String

```
arrayOfElements[0].data = malloc( strlen(str) + 1 );
strcpy( arrayOfElements[0].data, str );
```

And that all works. My Issue is how do I got about making a linked List and making each element store an instance of arrayOfElements

so far my linked list is

```
typedef struct LinkedListNode {
    void** ElementArray;
    struct LinkedListNode* next;
} LinkedListNode;

typedef struct {
    LinkedListNode* head;
} LinkedList;
```

so the void** ElementArray will point to each arrayOfElements

```
void insert(LinkedList* head, Element inArrayOfElements)
{ 
    LinkedListNode insertNode;

    /* Points ElementArray to inArrayOfElements */
    HOW DO I DO THIS AS ElementArray is a void**

    /* Points next to the head */
    (*insertNode).next = head;

    /* Re-points head to new head of Linked List */
    head = insertNode;
}
```

My Goal is to have something like this

```
LINKEDLIST
    +---+    +---+---+----+
    |   | -> |   |   |    |  arrayofElements
    +---+    +---+---+----+    +---+---+----+
    |   | -------------------> |   |   |    |
    +---+    +---+---+----+    +---+---+----+
    |   | -> |   |   |    |
    +---+    +---+---+----+    +---+---+----+
    |   | -------------------> |   |   |    |
    +---+                      +---+---+----+
```

**Question / TL;DR**
My question is how do I make void** ElementArray (in the linked list)  point to arrayOfElements.

Comment: Also I have to use a Linked List, otherwise i would've just done an array of pointers Many Thanks

Comment: do you really need a `void **` pointer? and how will you distinguish the various inserted types when everything is `void *` ?

Comment: Unless C is a hard requirement, I think using C++ for such things would yield results more quickly. Taking into account the hours ahead you will spend on fixing memory leaks and crashes when you access wrong types.

Comment: I have a way of tracking what types everything is, as the type of variable that will be stored by the struc Element is unknown but will remain constant ( im reading from a file)  so when I open the file I have a function to see what variable type it is

Comment: @ BitTickler  I have to use C

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, there is no need for double pointers. Just do:

```
typedef struct LinkedListNode {
    Element* data;
    struct LinkedListNode* next;
} LinkedListNode;


LinkedListNode* insert(LinkedListNode* head, Element* inArrayOfElements)
{ 
    LinkedListNode* insertNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));

    insertNode->next = head;
    insertNode->data = inArrayOfElements;
    return insertNode;
}
```

Use it like:

```
head = insert(head, someArrayOfElements);
```

**Note**: The real code should check for NULL pointers but I omitted that for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I needed a double pointer as when I malloc'd  the array of elements it was pointed to by a Element pointer called arrayOfElements
(4th line)